# Unity3d NavMesh refuses to bake anything but planes as walkable objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

Here is an example of an empty project that has a newly created cube as a Navigation Static with a walkable navigation area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd5Hj.png)

And here is a completely other project that I have worked on for a while.
Same baking settings, same plain cube as a navigation static with a walkable navigation area.

I do not want to port the whole freaking project to a new one just because nav mesh decided to not work at all out of the sudden. I have not even touched it up until that point and focused purely on coding basic stuff for the platformer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tphta.png)

Yet when I click bake...Nothing happens, literally no calculations or whatsoever. I even duplicated the project and scrapped EVERYTHING from it clean. Yet ONLY TERRAIN AND PLANES are ever calculated as walkables inside it and never any objects like basic cubes. What kind of setting or a hidden "feature" in Unity could cause this?

Removing everything from the project, even all prefabs, scripts etc, basically reverting it to the state of the clean slate it is when you create a new project, trying to find if any of stuff created by me is causing an error. Nope, clearly not my stuff, must be something in the unity setting itself.

Comment: its been a while - is the cube static?

Comment: Absolutely is.
The problem was in scaling.